# pdo bind variables to prepared mysql statement and fetch using while loop to display in table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I I am getting myself tangled with a pdo statement to display MySQL data in a table using pdo.

my syntax is:

```
 $startdate=$_POST["start"];
 $enddate=$_POST["end"];
 $ttype=$_POST["ttype"];

$result = $db->query("SELECT cycletype,commenttype,adminstatus FROM v2loads where haulier= :haulier and :start < sarrive and :end> sarrive order by sarrive"); 
$result->bindParam(':haulier', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result->bindParam(':start', $startdate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result->bindParam(':end', $enddate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result->execute;
```

I then try t fetch the output with

```
<table>
    <? while($row = $jobs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <? echo $row['cycletype'];?>
        <td>
        <td>
          <? echo $row['icommenttype];?>
        <td>
        <td>
          <? echo $row['adminstatus'];?>
        <td>
     </tr>
    <?  }  ?>
</table>
```

This produces error:
 Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your script:

```
    $startdate=$_POST["start"];
    $enddate=$_POST["end"];
    $ttype=$_POST["ttype"];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT cycletype,commenttype,adminstatus FROM v2loads where    haulier= :haulier and :start < sarrive and :end> sarrive order by sarrive"); 
    $result->bindParam(':haulier', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':start', $startdate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->bindParam(':end', $enddate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result->execute;
```

Change This To:

```
  $startdate=$_POST["start"];
  $enddate=$_POST["end"];
  $ttype=$_POST["ttype"];
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT cycletype,commenttype,adminstatus FROM v2loads where    haulier= :haulier and :start < sarrive and :end> sarrive order by sarrive"); 
  $result->bindParam(':haulier', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $result->bindParam(':start', $startdate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $result->bindParam(':end', $enddate, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $result->execute;
```

Then Try:

```
  <table>
  <? while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <? echo $row['cycletype'];?>
    <td>
    <td>
      <? echo $row['icommenttype];?>
    <td>
    <td>
      <? echo $row['adminstatus'];?>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <?  }  ?>
 </table>
```

You have used `bindparam` on a non object..USE `prepare` instead of `query`.

Answer (score 2):

That means that your query didn't parse, and $result isn't a PDO statement object. Dump [$db->errorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) for more details on the error.

It might be as simple as ":end>" needing a space before ">" -- I know that I tend to space such things out, maybe from past pain :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `prepare` method not `query` for a prepared statement.

And:

- method call needs parentheses else, for PHP, it will be a property: `$result->execute();` instead of `$result->execute;`
- you should iterate on $result not $jobs: `while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the fetch section of the answer.

`<? echo $row['icommenttype];?>` should be `<? echo $row['icommenttype'];?>`

I tried to edit it, but was denied because of SO's minimum 6 character edit policy.